# Correct way to describe inferred property with OWL and RDF

Tags: rdf, owl, rdfs, graphdb

I am trying to write an inference rule using OWL.

Given the following:

- A document is classified as having a category - let's say "Contract Law"
- There is a parent category "Law", with "Contract Law" as a sub-category
- I would like to infer that the document is also classified with "Law"

Statements:

```
@prefix : <http://example.com/> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

:Document rdf:type owl:Class .
:Category rdf:type owl:Class .

:documentHasCategory rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
                rdfs:domain :Document ;
                rdfs:range :Category .

:hasSubCategory rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
                rdfs:domain :Category ;
                rdfs:range :Category .

:category1 rdf:type :Category ;
      rdfs:label "Law" ;
      :hasSubCategory :category2 .

:category2 rdf:type :Category ;
      rdfs:label "Contract Law".

:doc1 rdf:type :Document ;
     :documentHasCategory :category2 .
```

How should I write an inference statement to add the category of "Law" to the document? I tried:

```
:inferredCategory rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
                 rdfs:domain :Document ;
                 rdfs:range :Category ;
                 owl:propertyChainAxiom ( :documentHasCategory :hasSubCategory ) .
```

But I'm not seeing any inferred statements (I'm using GraphDB).

Is `owl:propertyChainAxiom` the correct way to approach this?
Have I got my turtle syntax wrong?

Comment: Model these categories as OWL classes or see https://stackoverflow.com/q/48015890/7879193 (you should select the OWL-RL GraphDB "ruleset" for your repository).

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by "model these categories as OWL classes". Are they not?

Comment: I mean, as classes  of documents, `doc1 a :Document, :Category1`.

Comment: You’ll have to forgive me, I still don’t follow. Is this different to defining them with rdf:type statements? Please be as explicit as possible - thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't respecting the direction of the `hasSubCategory` predicate, so nothing actually matches the propertyChain rule.

Defining the inference like this works just fine:

```
:hasParentCategory rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
    owl:inverseOf :hasChildCategory .

:documentHasInferredCategory rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;
                rdfs:domain :Document ;
                rdfs:range :Category ;
                owl:propertyChainAxiom ( :documentHasCategory :hasParentCategory ) .
```